# Can Action Script FileReference object be sent to Javascript and converted to File object?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, filereference, file-io

In Action Script, FileReference.browse() is called.

I would like to send the chosen file to Javascript and convert it to File object, just like if I would press the `Browse` button of the `<input type='file />` and got File object.

I need that to be able to display picture thumbnail like shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications#section_5).

Maybe instead of passing the whole object it is possible to send only the required information for the thumbnail from the object ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to create a File object. For example, try this:

```
var f = new File;
```

I get an exception "Cannot convert WrappedNative to function." If you look in [the docs for File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File), there is no constructor described. Also, most of the attributes are read-only. I would interpret this to mean that only the browser can create a File object.

Keep in mind that if you could create a File object by specifying the path to a file, it would be easy to upload files without the user's consent. That would be a serious security hole.

You may find it more practical to use only Flash or only HTML5 for this.

Answer (score 1):

For people trying to do it. What can be done is:

1. Converting the fileReference data byterray to Base64 and put it in a string
2. Sending this string to javascript with ExternalInterface

I use this pattern in contexts where I want to have an overview of binary files content. Even a large image can be sent using this approach. The file can then be accessed in javascript using a data URI with the appropriate MIME:

data:image/png;base64,[data] or data:octet/stream,[data]

Since I'm posting almost 2 1/2 years after the first post, we can now do it in all popular browser.

Comment: That's what I am doing, works in Chrome but Firefox 41 crashes horribly with files larger than 4 MBs. Firefox rules NOT.

Comment: Yeah, at 4MB, it starts to be huge for an URI.